# Como trabalhar com mais de uma dependência em classe Service?

Tags: c#, design-pattern

Eu tenho minha classe `Service` chamada `GrupoService`, nela estão a maior parte da ações que se referem a um `Grupo`.

```
Crud(Inserir,Alterar,Excluir,Listar)
```

A única dependência que eu tenho na minha classe até então, é o `GrupoRepository`. Também tem-se nele, métodos, para inserir, alterar,excluir, deletar.

Então basicamente eu faço

```
public Grupo Inserir(Grupo model)
{
   return grupoRepository.Inserir(model);
}
```

Mas meu grupo contém `Itens`, qual é a maneira correta de injetar o `Item` na minha classe `GrupoService`?

Injetando o `ItemRepository` junto com `GrupoRepository`, ou eu colocar `ItemService`?

Comment: Se você está trabalhando com o Entity Framework, a melhor maneira é colocando em `model.Itens`, pois o Entity Framework resolve isso a nível de consistência. Separando demais você está criando um complicador e subutilizando a ferramenta.

Answer (score 3):

O ideal é que é que todo "Repository" seu receba no construtor uma instancia do Contexto de banco de dados (No caso do EntityFramework, o DbContext) ai você terá sempre o mesmo escopo de banco, transação e conexão.

E eu usaria o mesmo Repositorio do Grupo para Salvar os items, pois no seu "negócio" não se pode salvar um item apenas sem o grupo, concorda ?

Mais ou menos assim:

```
public class GrupoService
{
    IGrupoRepository _repository;
    public GrupoService(IGrupoRepository repository)
    {
         this._reposytory = reposiotory;

    }
    public Grupo Inserir(Grupo model)
    {
        return grupoRepository.Inserir(model);

        foreach(var item in model.Items)
        {
             grupoRepository.InserirItem(item);
        }
    }
}
public class GrupoRepository: IGrupoRepository 
{
    DbContext _db;
    public GrupoRepository(DbContext db)
    {
        this._db = db;
    }

    public Item InserirItem(Item model)
    {
        this._db.Items.Add(model);
        this._db.SaveChanges();
    }
}


//Usando
GrupoService gs = new GrupoService(new GrupoRepository( new MyDbContext("connString")));
```

Você pode tentar adaptar este exemplo a algum IoC que você esteja usando.

Comment: Concordo com tudo nessa resposta, mas e quanto aos `grupo.Itens`, que é o foco da pergunta?

Comment: Coloquei mais detalhes da idéia, pode ser melhorado, mas to sem tempo agora

Comment: é muito melhor estar utilizando um Repository Base, usando generic